# Django, StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: python, django

использовал я Streaming Http Responce в программе через ajax, на локалке всё работает прекрасно, на хостинге не работает, то есть на хостинге загружает сразу весь файл а мне этого не нужно, вопрос в том, почему так? (хостинг mchost, django 3.1 python 3.6)

Comment: прокси может какой помогает (nginx например)

Comment: прокси не заданы

Comment: может они (у них)  на хостинге по умолчанию стоят

Comment: я спросил у них, ответ - нет

Comment: можно попробовать сделать https, чтоб исключить всех между, иначе не знаю.

Comment: а если папка с сайтом и сам сайт по разному называються, может быть причиной?

Comment: Вряд ли; я не пишу на django; просто вспомнил, что было несколько похожих случаев с прокси; один раз мне именно надо было промежуточное звено, чтоб не занимать поток бэка на долгой заргузке;  другой раз SSE запросы не шли нормально, оказалось у клиента прокси -- через https всё заработало;